# Parse objectID returns null in Android

Tags: java, android, parse-platform

```
private String clockInId;
public void clockIn(View v) {
    SimpleDateFormat sdfTime = new SimpleDateFormat("hh:mm:ss a", Locale.US);
    final String clockInTime = sdfTime.format(new Date(System.currentTimeMillis()));
    final ParseObject clockIn = new ParseObject("clockIn");
    clockIn.put("Time", clockInTime);
    clockIn.saveEventually(new SaveCallback() {
        @Override
        public void done(ParseException e) {
            clockInId = clockIn.getObjectId();  //Save objectID that was just created
        }
    });
    Toast toast = Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Clocked In!",Toast.LENGTH_LONG);
    toast.show();
    Log.d(TAG, "objId:" + clockInId);
}
```

`getObjectId()` keeps returning null, what am I missing? The parse object saves fine.

Comment: Where are you saving `objectId` in your object?

Comment: saveEventually.done block is ASYNC....  on a seperate thread , executing AFTER  "Log clockIndId"

Comment: @RobertRowntree Any tips on how to go about this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I changed `saveEventually` to `saveInBackground`:

```
clockIn.saveInBackground(new SaveCallback() {
    @Override
    public void done(ParseException e) {
        clockInId = clockIn.getObjectId();  //Save objectID that was just created
        Log.d(TAG, "objId:" + clockInId);
    }
```